# C++ API - what is the right approach

Tags: c++, api, dll

I have to build an API for a C++ framework which do some simulation stuff. I already have created a new class with `__declspec(dllexport)` functions and built the framework to a DLL.
This works fine and I can use the framework within a C# application.
But is there another or a better approach to create an API with C++?

Comment: Are you looking for a redistribution-approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with exporting classes have some serious drawbacks. You won't be able to write DLLs in another languages, because they don't support name mangling. Furthermore, you won't be able to use other compilers than VS (because of the same reason). Furthermore, you may not be able to use *another version* of VS, because MS doesn't guarantee, that mangling mechanism stays the same in different versions of the compiler.

I'd suggest using flattened C-style interface, eg.

```
MyClass::Method(int i, float f);
```

Export as:

```
MyClass_MyMethod(MyClass * instance, int i, float f);
```

You can wrap it inside C# to make it a class again.

Comment: It's not just the mangling, if the definition of std::string or std::vector for example is changed between versions you will be unable to reliably use those in an interface (and worse, it might actually compile and link...)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a C++-API, exporting a set of classes from a DLL/shared library is the way to go. Many libraries written in C++ decide to offer a C interface though, because pure C interfaces are much easier to bind to foreign languages. To bind foreign languages to C++, a wrapper generator such as SWIG is typically required.

C++-APIs also have the problem that, due to C++ name-mangling, the same compiler/linker needs to be used to build the framework and the application.

It is important to note that the `__declspec(dllexport)`-mechanism of telling the compiler that a class should be exported is specific to the Microsoft Compiler. It is common practice to put it into a preprocessor macro to be able to use the same code on other compilers:

```
 #ifdef _MSC_VER 
 #   define MY_APP_API __declspec(dllexport)
 #else
 #   define MY_APP_API
 #endif

 class MY_APP_API MyClass {}
```